# Find element by XPath in Selenium with Python can not catch an exception

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to play videos automatically through [this page](https://www.lynda.com/CSS-tutorials/Welcome/417645/484766-4.html?autoplay=true) by click the <kbd>Next</kbd> bottom. However, at the end of each chapter, there is an exercise page without a video, and I want to skip it.

The skip-to-next-chapter button element is on every page, just not visible.

(1) on exercise page, wait for the page to be loaded

(2) find the skip-to-next-chapter button and click on it

(3) on the video page, skip-to-next-chapter is not visible, so skip this block

However, I can not catch any exceptions, so the process got stuck at the `next_ = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[foo]')` line. This line doesn’t return anything and run forever. And it won’t throw a Timeout exception.

How can I debug this?

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'myID')))
    next_ = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[foo]')
    next_.click()
except (NoSuchElementException ,ElementNotVisibleException,TimeoutException):
    print('skip this')
```

changed to

```
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "skip-to-next-chapter", " " ))]'))
    ).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
```

But it still does not work.

Debug final stop point from [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tzmU.png)

When stepping into `EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "skip-to-next-chapter", " " ))]'))` line, it goes to wait.py >>

```
    def until(self, method, message=''):
    """Calls the method provided with the driver as an argument until the \
    return value is not False."""
    screen = None
    stacktrace = None

    end_time = time.time() + self._timeout
    while True:
        try:
            value = method(self._driver)# <<<< stopped here!!
            if value:
                return value
        except self._ignored_exceptions as exc:
            screen = getattr(exc, 'screen', None)
            stacktrace = getattr(exc, 'stacktrace', None)
        time.sleep(self._poll)
        if time.time() > end_time:
            break
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Comment: Can you share the url as well?So we can test our system as well

Comment: Try given a not exists ID and xpath in your code then run script again,  if script can catch exception means the two elements:  `myID` and `//[foo]` exactly exist on the page, you need to adjustment  your code.

Comment: I found that the element 'skip-to-next-chapter' button is always exist but not visible on [this](https://www.lynda.com/CSS-tutorials/Welcome/417645/484766-4.html?autoplay=true), still dont know how to skip it

Answer (score 1):

You have to take care of a couple of things in your code block. In your code block as you have tried to handle three exceptions and among them `NoSuchElementException` and `ElementNotVisibleException` looks as a pure overhead to me for the following reasons:

- First of all, I am still trying to understand the logic behind waiting for an `elementA` (i.e. `(By.ID, 'myID')`), but moving ahead and clicking on `elementB`, i.e., `find_element_by_xpath('//*[foo]')`
- If your code block is generating `NoSuchElementException`, definitely we have to look at the [**`Locator Strategy`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements) which you have adapted if it uniquely identifies an element and also cross-check that the element is within the [**`Viewport`**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- If your code block is generating `ElementNotVisibleException`, we have to consider this factor as well when we pick up the **EC** clause, e.g., [**`presence_of_element_located`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located).
- Finally, as moving forward you are attempting to invoke the `click()` method on the element, instead of the **EC** clause as `presence_of_element_located`, you should be using [**`element_to_be_clickable(locator)`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable)
- So to `wait` for an element and moving ahead to `click` it, your code block will be like:

  ```
   try:
       WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'myID'))).click()
   except (TimeoutException):
       print('skip this')
  ```

Comment: I have tried the suggested code, however, `WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'myID'))).click()` dont return anything ,so no exception can not be caught .
when the element is visible this code works well, when the element is hidden it stopped cause nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what’s wrong with my code. Why doesn’t WebDriver return anything when it can not find the element? Anyway, I walk way from this by another way.

1. Use [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) to parse the page source
2. Check if the button exists
3. if exist → driver, click it

if not → skip

```
src = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

next_chap = soup.find('button',class_="btn btn-link skip-to-next-chapter ga")

if(next_chap!=None):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-link.skip-to-next-chapter.ga').click()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
else:
    print("button not exists ,skip")
```